# 'Grub Rescue' is the most irritating problem that makes me want to pull my hair out

Tags: 13.10, lubuntu, grubrescue

I have rescued my old computer for use as a wee testing ground for Linux OS. I considered trying Lubuntu 13.10 on it but I get this strange 'grub rescue' prompt (something like 'cannot read or write outside hd0) when I try to boot.
I have Googled many times for this error and used various methods that is supposed to fix this problem but to no avail. I have tried

- editing grub.cfg and update-grub in Live CD
- reinstalling Lubuntu 13.10 from Live CD
- trying Boot-Repair in Live CD

I do not know why this problem occurs and it has been bugging me for a while and I need help fixing this computer.

Here are my old computer specs: AMD Athlon Processor, 855MHz, 512MB RAM

Thank you very much,
BlueHattedEngie

Answer (score 0):

If possible, remove the hard drive from the computer, connect it to another computer, and completely wipe the drive. Then put it back into the computer and try installing Lubuntu again.